# Is there any way to use openFileOutput() method in non-Activity class?

Tags: android, file-io, android-activity

Is there any way to use `openFileOutput()` method in non-Activity class ?

I have private class extends `AsyncTask` and I want to execute that method in `onPostExecute()`, but I cannot do that, because my IDE shows following error :

> The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type
>   FunkcjeAPI.Logowanie

What are alternatives ? I tried to use `getActivity().openFileOutput()`, but then I see same error.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Ther is no `openFileStream()` method in Android.

Comment: Yes, there is : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: That method is not named `openFileStream()`. You can tell that by reading.

Comment: I changed that, still same error....

Comment: Then you are typing something in wrong. `openFileOutput()` is a method on `Context`, `Activity` inherits from `Context`, and `getActivity()` returns an `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor for your AsyncTask and pass in the context so you can use it later.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long> {

    private Context context;

    public MyTask (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // other code...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // use context here
    }
}
```

Then, to execute the task:

```
new MyTask(this).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding to the constructor of my `AsyncTask` `Context` object and typing :

```
context.openFileOutput();
```